# Domain verified for sending how can I verify it for receiving in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simple-email-service

I have a domain let's call it www.example.com. I have verified the domain in SES for sending, didn't verify it for receiving emails in SES. Is there any way I verify it for receiving without having to restart the verification for sending as well as receiving?

Comment: I don't think there is a verification for receiving email. Have you verified the domain? Is receiving not working? Have you configured it to use S3 or SNS?

Comment: I have to add SES given the MX record to verify for receiving. I can see txt record on my SES dashboard for the given domain but cant see MX record.